# Cant get my mergeSort working after several hours

Tags: java, mergesort

*Hey. So i got a problem with my mergeSorting. I have tried different approaches and methods but cant get it to work. I understand the principle of the mergeSorting so no problem there. 
This is my my methods:

```
public static void TopDownMergeSort(int[] left, int[] right, int n){
    TopDownSplitMerge(left, 0, n, right);
}

public static void CopyArray(int[] right, int start, int end, int[] left){
    for (int i = start;i < end; i++){
        right[i] = left[i]; 
    }
}

public static void TopDownSplitMerge(int[] left, int start, int end, int[] right){
    if (end - start < 2){
        int middle = (end + start)/2;
        TopDownSplitMerge(left, start, middle, right);
        TopDownSplitMerge(left, middle, end, right);
        TopDownMerge(left, start, middle, end, right);
        CopyArray(right, start, end, left);
    }
}

public static void TopDownMerge(int[]left, int start, int middle, int end, int[]right){

    int i1 = start, i2 = middle;

    for (int i = start; i < end; i++){
        if (i1 < middle && (i2 >= end || left[i1] <= left[i2])){
            right[i] = left[i1++];
        }
        else {
            right[i] = left[i2++];
        }
    }
}

public static int[] mergeSort(int[] in) {
    int[] arr = in.clone();
    int[] temp = in.clone();

    TopDownSplitMerge(arr,0,arr.length,temp);
    return arr;
}
```

And this is how i test mergeSort.

```
int[] list = {2,5,8,6,9,7,3,4};

        System.out.println("Before mergesort: "+Arrays.toString(list));

        int[] ne = SortingAlgorithms.mergeSort(list);

        System.out.println("After mergesort: "+Arrays.toString(ne));
```

Comment: What is the expected output? What's the actual?

Comment: The expected result is of course a sorted array.
And the result is : Before mergesort: [2, 5, 8, 6, 9, 7, 3, 4]
After mergesort: [2, 5, 8, 6, 9, 7, 3, 4]

Comment: I would suggest using Lists instead of arrays and actually split the list. Juggling with indexes is error-prone.

Comment: Okey. Yeah i looked at wikipedias solution and thought that would do the trick but wasnt so simple anyway. :/

Answer (score 1):

```
if (end - start < 2)
```

is wrong. It should be

```
if (end - start > 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:
`CopyArray` can be replaced by `System.arraycopy`... Also rethink the: `if (end - start < 2)`

Instead of fix the code, I recommend you to check the book Introduction to Algorithms by Thomas H. Cornmen

Comment: Okey. Thanks for the help. will look into it and read more about it :)